# Lyon public transit ticket conditions?

Tags: public-transport, lyon

http://www.tcl.fr/en/Fares/Fares/Single-ticket/Ticket says "(DESCRIPTION EN ATTENTE)" which Google says is simply "Description is waiting".

So what are the conditions? Is it valid only for a single ride? Or can I at least transfer between underground lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the English page doesn't have a description the [French one](http://www.tcl.fr/Tarifs/Tickets/Ticket-a-l-unite/Ticket-a-l-unite) *does* (h/t JonathanReez). I ran it through Google Translate and it's reasonably understandable:

> A ticket is valid for a trip, over the entire TCL network, during the hour following its first validation. It is possible to end a journey beyond one hour if the last validation (and therefore correspondence) takes place before the limit of one hour. Return trips are allowed with the same ticket.

Answer (score 3):

Tickets are valid for any number of rides within a time limit (so yes, you can transfer).

The time limit depends on the type of ticket.

The standard ticket will pass additional validations for one hour after first use.  The ticket needs to be validated at the *beginning* of each ride only—it doesn't matter how long the ride takes.  You can get on a bus (and re-validate you ticket) 1 minute before the ticket expires, and get off half an hour later.

There are other tickets that may me more advantageous.  For example, the evening ticket (*soirée*) is valid from 7 PM until the end of service that day.

Ticket machines do have an English interface.